# Solving a system of equations with unknown functions

Tags: calculus, functions, systems-of-equations

I know there are lots of ways to solve a system of equations with unknown variables, but in physics most of the time people do the opposite, they gatter data from a phenomena and turn that data into a function using different methods then solve equations related to that phenomena to predict its future states. 

Now my question is can we find a solution just from the data, skipping the whole data to function step because it's time and energy consuming. Assuming we have three equations like this:
$$\begin{cases} d_{0}=f_{0}(a,b,c)\\ d_{1}=f_{1}(a,b,c)\\ d_{2}=f_{2}(a,b,c)  \end{cases}$$ we know few things about this system;

- if we have a,b,c we can examine the system and get d, but we can't do the opposite.
- we know that the output of any of these functions and the variables are in a fixed range 0 <= d,a,b,c<=M (M is not a variable)
- for simplicity a,b,c,d ∈ N (natural numbers)
- there are no known function between the variables (ex: a=g(b), d0=f(d2) ..) (there could be but we don't know)
- we know that there exist at least one solution

with this in mind can we find [a,b,c] if we have [d0,d1,d2] ?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, we usually have a reason to suspect that certain functions will take certain forms. We then use curve fitting algorithms to fit the curves to the data.

Comment: @JohnDouma yes, my question is about skipping the whole curve fitting process, is there a way of finding solutions directly from raw data instead

Comment: @JohnDouma sometimes curve fitting takes a lot of computation power and time, is there an alternative?

Comment: That's not possible because there are always an infinite number of curves that will go through $n$ points and at least as many as go close by. Are you familiar with countably infinite sets vs uncountably infinite sets? There are more functions that go through those points than there are names for functions.

Comment: @JohnDouma yes I understand, but the function is only defined in natural numbers, and it goes through all points in a range, also it has one or more solutions

Comment: @JohnDouma any function within that range will work